# Unable to see the image from a .npy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

Tried the below code to read the image which is a .npy file but was getting the below error

Input[This is the link to download the images where the file size is >10GB](https://zenodo.org/record/4280482/files/S2MTCP_data.7z?download=1)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import glob


for filename in glob.glob("*.*"):
    if '.npy' in filename:
        img_array = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        img_name = filename+".png"
        matplotlib.image.imsave(img_name, img_array)
        print(filename)
```

Output

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (601, 660, 14) for image data
```

Comment: how is the file being saved? as you can see by the error, the image is an irregular shape and is probably being saved/loaded incorrectly

Comment: The image is a .npy file , i'm converting it to a .png file , when we see the shape of the image, the dimension of the image is 14 , when i tried to read the .npy file , it consists of array of numbers

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: From the `imshow` documentation: Supported array shapes are (M, N) or (M, N, 3) or (M, N, 4). But your `img_array` is (M,N,14). Maybe your `img_array` contains the data of 14 different 601x660 images?

Comment: As per the dataset , its not a single image , its image pair , and we have a csv file along with it , will this information help to solve this ??

Comment: “code to read the image” ... but that is not what the code does. It reads a 3D matrix from a file, then attempt to show it as a 2D image, which of course it is not, and then attempts to save it as a 2D  image to a PNG file, which also would fail. We cannot tell you how to fix your code because you don’t explain what you want to do. Do you have 14 images, is this a single 3D image, is it a 2D image with 14 channels? Why do you want to save this 3D matrix as PNG files? Is the intention to load it elsewhere? Or just to look at it? Please [edit] your question with all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

My best understanding is, you want to plot 14 (or whatever…) images for each data set, and this can be done as follows

```
norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(img_array), np.max(img_array))
for n, xy in enumerate(np.transpose(img_array, (2,1,0))):
    plt.imshow(xy, cmap='gray', norm=norm)
    fname = base+"%2.2d"%n+".png'
    ...
```

If you want to have each image scaled independently from the others, omit all the `norm` stuff, if you want to exchange column and rows in the images, use
`np.transpose(img_array, (2,0,1)))`

---

Example:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y, Z = 11, 13, 3
images = np.arange(X*Y*Z).reshape(Z,Y,X).transpose((1,2,0))
cm = 'gray'
norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(images), np.max(images))
normalize = 0
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, constrained_layout=True)
fig.suptitle('''\
Top: each image is indipendently normalized.
Bottom: all images are equally normalized.''')
for row in axes:
    for ax, image in zip(row, images.transpose((2,0,1))):
        if normalize:
            im = ax.imshow(image, cmap=cm, norm=norm)
        else:
            im = ax.imshow(image, cmap=cm)
            plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    if normalize:
        plt.colorbar(im, ax=row, location='bottom')
    normalize = 1
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , output 
NameError: name 'base' is not defined along with the image

Comment: `base` stands for the base name of the output file, I don't know _exactly_ what you want/need to do, but I expect that you can to fill in the blanks, cannot you?

Comment: Is there a way we can use opencv to have this sorted ??

Comment: Never used `opencv`, cannot answer.